# Check if record exists in Edge table (Graph DB) [in a re-usable way]

Tags: sql-server, graph-databases

I'm hoping someone can help me with the query to see whether a record exists within a graph edge table in SQL Server.

I want to insert a node relationship if that relationship doesn't already exist. In a 'normal' SQL table I could do something like this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
 SELECT
  [from],
  [to]
 FROM
  [EdgeTable]
 WHERE
  [from] = (SELECT [id] FROM [NodeTable] WHERE [data] = 'some value')
  AND [to] = (SELECT [id] FROM [NodeTable] WHERE [data] = 'some other value')
)
BEGIN
...
```

My problem is that in a MS Graph table, it's not 'from' and 'to' but rather '$from_id_xxxxx' and '$to_id_xxxxx' where xxxxx is a hex code.

While for a once off I could hard code these into my SQL query, I'm trying to build a script that would be used across multiple databases and so the hex code might be different in each one.

I hope that makes sense?

Comment: For additional information, I'm building a 'data warehouse generator' in Python, that will use a mixture of yml and basic SQL select queries. I want it to generate an audit table which contains all of the fact/dim/stg tables and their sources (and data lineage). A graph table seems like the best approach here, if I can crack the above question.
Given the nature of this Python script, it would be used across multiple clients to build their warehouses, hence would need to work with multiple edge tables which seem to have fields appended with random hex.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, sorry - I was being really dumb.

I've got into the habit of putting square braces around my table and field names. Seems you can't do this with the auto-generated Graph table fields.

This works:

```
SELECT 
  $from_id,
  $to_id
FROM 
  [audit].[tableMetaDataEdge]
WHERE
  $from_id = (SELECT $node_id FROM [audit].[tableMetaDataNode] WHERE [table] = '[staging].[dbo].[Customer]')
```

This doesn't:

```
SELECT 
  [$from_id],
  [$to_id]
FROM 
  [audit].[tableMetaDataEdge]
WHERE
  [$from_id] = (SELECT [$node_id] FROM [audit].[tableMetaDataNode] WHERE [table] = '[staging].[dbo].[Customer]')
```

I thought I needed to write:

```
SELECT 
  [$from_id_F86BBF0BA19E42E281261CBC981504F6],
  [$to_id_82880261B4804F359608E084465D6535]
FROM 
  [audit].[tableMetaDataEdge]
WHERE
  [$from_id_F86BBF0BA19E42E281261CBC981504F6] = (SELECT $node_id FROM [audit].[tableMetaDataNode] WHERE [table] = '[staging].[dbo].[Customer]')
```

And I couldn't work out how to get the hex values for the field names. Turns out, by removing the square brackets, you don't actually need them.